# How to fix cant retrieve data with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

i should tell you my code is actually work, but a litle bit of annoying problem i cant solve by my self.

The problem is i only can retrieve the first record(id) from my data grid but i cant retrieve the second or other record id

example :
when i click my edit button of my first record of my data then i want to send the id to my jquery and show it in console and use it for selecting data form database (this is work)

but when i click edit of my second record of my data it wont send data to my Jquery and show it in console

This is my Grid code

```
    <?php foreach($data['gakubu_data'] as $gakubu):?>
        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center"><?= $gakubu['code_gakubu'];?> | <?= $gakubu['gakubu'];?>

        <a href="" data-code="<?= $gakubu['code_gakubu']?>" id="showUpdateModal" class="badge badge-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#formModal">編集</a>
        </li>

    <?php endforeach;?> 

    </div>
</div>
```

this is my Jquery Script

```
$(function(){

$('#showUpdateModal').on('click',function(){

    $('#formModalLabel').html('データ編集');
    $('.modal-footer button[type=submit]').html('データ編集');
    const id = $(this).data('code');
    console.log(id);


 });
});
```

Comment: this is my CDN<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha384-3ceskX3iaEnIogmQchP8opvBy3Mi7Ce34nWjpBIwVTHfGYWQS9jwHDVRnpKKHJg7" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: Please edit your question to include code/info instead of in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop creates multiple elements with the same id (`id="showUpdateModal"`). Id's *must* be unique within a document, so when you select it with: `$('#showUpdateModal')`, it will always return the first element with that id (since there shouldn't be any more elements with the same id).

You can solve it by using a class instead:

```
<a href="" data-code="<?= $gakubu['code_gakubu']?>" class="showUpdateModal badge badge-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#formModal">編集</a>
```

(I removed the id and added `showUpdateModal` as a class instead)

Now you can register the event on the class instead:

```
$('.showUpdateModal').on('click', function() {
    // Your current code
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help brother

Comment: @shinichirouikebe - If the answer solved your issue, please accept it so others know it's been resolved.